# expanded-item not triggering events

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I'm currently having the problem that when the checkboxes in the expanded-item slot are clicked, these do not change their value.

I have also tried using the directive @click, but this also didn't trigger the checkbox to change its value.

```
<template>
                <v-data-table
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="items"
                    show-expand
                    single-expand
                >
                    <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item, headers }">
                        <td :colspan="headers.length">
                            <v-row v-for="(cs, index) in item.c" :key="index">
                                <v-simple-checkbox
                                    v-model="cs.selected"
                                    :ripple="false"
                                >
                                </v-simple-checkbox>
                            </v-row>
                        </td>
                    </template>
                </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
data() {
        return {
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'A',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'a'
                },
                {
                    text: 'B',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'b'
                }
            ],
            items: [
                { a: 'my A', b: 'my B', c: [false, false] },
                { a: 'my A', b: 'my B', c: [false, false] }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Link to reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-1omj9p?file=/src/layout.vue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select the checkboxes of expanded panel after clicking them. Please see if this is what you are looking for. You also need to give a unique field for each row in items so that selecting checkboxes works ( I have added id field here). Once we click the button, selected checkboxes id can be captured (check console.log).

Link https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-6u5wry

```
 <template>
 <v-app>
    <v-main>
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items"
            show-expand
            single-expand
        >
            <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item, headers }">
                <td :colspan="headers.length">
                    <v-data-table
                        :headers="headers"
                        :items="items"
                        class="elevation-1"
                        v-model="selected"
                        show-select
                        item-key="id"
                        :hide-default-header="true"
                        :hide-default-footer="true"
                        :footer-props="{ itemsPerPageOptions: [-1] }"
                    >
                    </v-data-table>
                </td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
        <v-btn
            small
            color="blue darken-4"
            rounded
            dark
            @click.prevent="selectcheckbox"
            >Check Selected</v-btn
        >
    </v-main>
   </v-app>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
   components: {
    //MyDialog: () => import('./features/dialog.vue'),
    //MyTabs: () => import('./features/tabs'),
    //DatePicker: () => import('./features/date-picker.vue')
   },
   data() {
    return {
        selected: [],
        headers: [
            {
                text: 'A',
                align: 'center',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'a'
            },
            {
                text: 'B',
                align: 'center',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'b'
            }
        ],
        items: [
            { id: 1, a: 'my A', b: 'my B', c: [false, false] },
            { id: 2, a: 'my A', b: 'my B', c: [false, false] }
        ]
    }
   },
   methods: {
    selectcheckbox() {
        console.log('selected checkboxes', this.selected)
    }
    }
   }
   </script>

   <style>
   .b1,
   [b1] {
   border: 1px dashed red;
   }

  .h-100 {
   height: 100%;
  }
   .w-100 {
   width: 100%;
   }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  }

  .v-btn,
  .v-tabs__item {
  text-transform: none !important;
  }
  </style>
```

[image]